# jenkins assign roles to views

Tags: security, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins, which is integrated with AD, using Global Security.
I know already, that I can assign, with Role Strategy Plugin, role-based access for some AD users\groups to particular projects.

My question - is there any way to assign role-based access for some AD users\groups to project views, not for single projects?

Comment: There is a [open request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/role-strategy-plugin/pull/21) for. To solve this problem I use folder instead of view to organize jobs

Comment: @JoaoVitorino thanks for your reply